# Production build fail after Angular upgrade document.documentElement.setAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular16

I have upgraded my application to Angular 16 and upgrade went well and application is working as expected

But when I run the command for prod build

```
ng build --configuration=production
```

I got this error

```
Index html generation failed.
document.documentElement.setAttribute is not a function
```

I am not sure how to fix this as I don't have documentElement.setAttribute in my code

Setting optimization and buildOptimizer to false in angular.json does work but I know this is not right way to fix

any help or suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: I have a feeling that this is related to `inlineCritical`. Can you try to just disable it with :               `"optimization": {"styles": {"inlineCritical": false }}` in your prod build ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler It worked perfectly but how this is different from **"optimization" : false** ?

Comment: `optimization` is a set of options which can be finely tuned see https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#optimization-configuration. Since I could not reproduce your issue, could you try to narrow it down in a GitHub repo ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler It worked great. Please put it as an answer.

Answer (score 13):

Try remove node_modules and package-lock.json then run npm install

Comment: This solution worked for me! Re-created the package-lock.json and pushed the new one with the rest of the code

Answer (score 1):

I got this the same error while am upgrading angular 15 to 16 and resolved by changing angular.json as `"optimization" : false`.

Thanks to @Matthieu Riegler for their hint in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I will post this as an answer and save it, because it fixed the problem.

In `angular.json` change the optimization configuration to:
`"optimization": {"styles": {"inlineCritical": false }}`